# Moving Codeigniter 2.1 to a webhost produces MySQL database problems

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have developed a PHP application that processes relatively large text files, and stores the results in a MySQL database table.
The file is the Bible, and thus every database entry is a verse with its references. The amount of entries therefore are just over 31,000 per table.

The program is working perfectly on my OS X localhost XAMPP installation, but when I move it to the webhost it only inserts 1 entry; which is the very last line of the text file. Even though I do every line as its own query, it appears that CodeIgniter is only taking the last entry. Where the whole process runs for about 22 to 30 seconds on localhost it runs for a mere 2 seconds on the webhost, so I'm sure it does not run through all the queries.

Have anyone else had a similar issue? I'm thinking it can't be my code since it works perfect on localhost.

> General server information:
>   Operating system  linux
>   Kernel version    2.6.9-89.0.19.ELsmp
>   Machine Type  i686
>   Apache version    2.2.21
>   PHP version   5.2.17
>   MySQL version 5.1.56

Comment: Give some debug info, like some informations what happens when processing files, some sql that are sent to server etc. Turn on error_reporting and display errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved when I used `chr(13).chr(10)` instead of `\r\n` in my code.